# I don't understand how this phrase is calculated in c#

Tags: c#

I test this code

```
int value = (char)+(int)-(float)+(double)-1;
```

and I get this result (1) that means value is `1`! How is this calculated?

EDIT:

I had an interview yesterday in a company and this was their question, and I did not know how this number was obtained `1`. So I am trying to understand how this result comes about.

Comment: Could you explain why you even would do this?

Comment: This  'code' makes no sense at all. When it is pseudo code or a puzzle then you are missing some explanation.

Comment: +1 because this weird stuff even compiles. I would give +1 more if I could that you even came up with this stuff

Comment: You should edit it to add what you try to acomplish

Comment: @AminSaadati That's what happens if you ask "bogus" questions, it may not be bogus but it *looks* like it. And in no actual real world application would someone cast 4x to get a number, they would just cast to the type they need. These are not my views but I'm trying to explain why someone might downvote

Comment: @EpicKip I think the point is that OP didn't know it was casting because it looks like a mathematical expression

Comment: @DavidG Might be but I don't see any indication the OP does not know it is casting and judging on the comments I made my comment :)

Comment: @EpicKip I had an interview yesterday in a company and this was their question, and I did not know how this number was obtained (1). Because of this, I asked you this question.I am also looking to learn the basics of programming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is really just a lot of casting. The `+` and `-` signs are only being used to negate the number. So take the first bit of the expression, that casts `-1` to a `double`:

```
(double)-1
```

Then take the result of that and cast it to `float`:

```
(float)+(-1)
```

And so on until you end with a `char` that is implicitly cast to an `int`.

Comment: @GiulioCaccin If you mean the compiled code, then yes you are right. But semantically the code is casting.

Comment: The casting has little to do with the result though, the calculation is essentially: `var value = +-+-1;//=1`

Comment: I want to point out that also the operations are not happening.

Answer (score 5):

The calls:

- `int value = (char)+(int)-(float)+(double)-1;`
- `int value = (int)-(float)-1;`
- `int value = 1;`

Have the same Intermediate Language that push the number 1 into the evaluation stack:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    // <-- push to stack
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // value
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // value
IL_0004:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump<Int32>
IL_0009:  pop         
IL_000A:  ret
```

Optimization reduce your operation to a simple assigment.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of simple arithmetics:

`(double)-1`   is calculated to  `-1`

`(float)+(double)-1`   is calculated to `-1`

`(int)-(float)+(double)-1`   is calculated to `+1`

`(char)+(int)-(float)+(double)-1`  is calculated to `+1`